# Jump to entry point of ELF from loader

Tags: c, libc

Thanks to the help in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552126/memset-memcpy-on-mmap-region-fails) question, the loader can now map a statically compiled hello world into memory and jump somewhere in that memory region. The problem I'm facing now is I seem not to jump to the right address or I'm calling the function in the wrong way (or wrong function?).

Below is the code to try; I can't find in glibc where the loader calls the entry point of the program to verify I'm doing the right thing. I tried:

- Calling _start(void)
- Calling _start(int, char**, char**)
- Calling __libc_start_main with the last parameters set to NULL (found [here](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html))
- Calling directly main
- Calling some addresses in  (found with gdb in rdi: 400B4D, r8: 4018E0, rcx: 401840)

The entry point is 0x400a30, some instructions below __libc_start_main. With some of them it SIGSEGV, SIGABRT or prints:

```
hello, world! haswell xeon_phi ../csu/libc-start.c FATAL: kernel too old
   __ehdr_start.e_phentsize == sizeof *GL(dl_phdr) unexpected reloc type in static binary  FATAL: cannot determine kernel version
 __libc_start_main /dev/full /dev/null   cannot set %fs base address for thread-local storage :  %s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.
%n        Unexpected error.
```

and some hundred of junk lines.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[argc+1]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size_t sz = ftell(fp) + 1;
    rewind(fp);

    char *region = mmap(NULL, sz, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fileno(fp), 0);
    if (region == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not mmap");
        return 1;
    }

    Elf64_Ehdr elf64Ehdr;
    memmove(&elf64Ehdr, region, sizeof(elf64Ehdr));

    size_t offset;
    Elf64_Phdr elf64Phdr;
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i != elf64Ehdr.e_phnum; ++i) {
        offset = elf64Ehdr.e_phoff + i * elf64Ehdr.e_phentsize;
        memmove(&elf64Phdr, region + offset, sizeof(elf64Phdr));
        switch (elf64Phdr.p_type) {
            case PT_NULL:
                break;
            case PT_LOAD:
                if (load(&elf64Phdr, region + elf64Phdr.p_offset)) {
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("jumping to: 0x%x\n", elf64Ehdr.e_entry);

    char *argv1[] = {"", NULL};

    int ret = ((int (*)(int, char **, char **)) elf64Ehdr.e_entry)(1, argv1, argv1);
    return ret;
}

int load(const Elf64_Phdr *phdr, const void *elf_bytes_for_phdr) {
    const size_t pagesize = getpagesize();
    const size_t unaligned_bytes = phdr->p_vaddr % pagesize;

    void *base_addr = phdr->p_vaddr - unaligned_bytes;
    size_t total_bytes = phdr->p_memsz + unaligned_bytes;

    void *region = mmap(base_addr, total_bytes,
            phdr->p_flags | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    if (region != MAP_FAILED) {
        memset(region, 0, unaligned_bytes);
        return memcpy(region + unaligned_bytes, elf_bytes_for_phdr, phdr->p_filesz) != region + unaligned_bytes && 
        ! mprotect(region, total_bytes, phdr->p_flags);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something; it looks like you're calling elf64Ehdr.e_entry directly, i.e. without offsetting by the base address (region)...?

Answer (score 4):

> The problem I'm facing now is I seem not to jump to the right address or I'm calling the function in the wrong way

Your problem is neither of the above (although "calling the wrong way" is not too far).

For a statically-linked executable, `Elf64_Ehdr.e_entry` is the correct address to call (it points to `_start`), and `_start` takes no arguments.

The problem is that it is the job of `_start` to

1. initialize libc, and
2. to find correct values of `argc`, `argv` and `envp`, and finally
3. to call `main(argc, argv, envp)`.

The question then is: how can `_start` accomplish step 2?

The answer: there is a protocol that Linux kernel *implements* and `_start` *uses* to accomplish step 2.

In particular, the kernel copies the actual (string) values of `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, ... `envp[0]`, `envp[1]`, etc. to the stack, then the pointers to these strings. There is also something called auxilliary vector.

The `_start` *expects* to find all of this info on the stack, and will misbehave when it doesn't find it. I believe that is the root cause of your current problem.

Here is an [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) which explains expected setup with references to Linux kernel source code. Another [article](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/stack-layout.html).

Comment: Said more simply, the entry point is not a C function. The contract for entry requires specific initial values for certain registers, and the main argument is a pointer to the vector of argc, argv entries, environment entries, aux, that arrives in the stack pointer.

Comment: I like those two articles, link more! Back to my question: is my only option to push to the stack argc and the addresses of argv and env using inline asm (or plain linked asm)? Calling _start with (argc, argv, env) in fact does not help. What is `Elf64_Ehdr.e_start`? I see no ref. to it. + @R..

Comment: @bicup Sorry, I meant `.e_entry` (you are already doing it). And yes, you *must* make the stack look *exactly* the way kernel prepares it and `_start` expects.

Comment: @bicup: "Calling" `_start` (rather `e_entry`) without asm is impossible in general because it's not a function. For some archs, it may be possible to write a function call where the ABI constraints happen to guarantee the right properties for the ELF entry point, but that's even worse than (and equally arch-specific as) writing asm.

Comment: @R.. I wrote a simple [function](https://pastebin.com/Q7AenWAj) in x64 that pushes 1 (argc), and 3 times <pointer to string "hi", NULL> (argv, env, aux) and it crashes at 0x0. Could it depend on _start not reading from the stack but registers in x64?

Comment: @bicup: You're pushing in the wrong order (backwards), and `"hi"` is not a valid environment string (it lacks an `'='` character) nor a valid auxv entry (they are not strings but pairs of (usually small) integer key and integer or pointer value.

Comment: @R.. the stack [now looks good](https://pastebin.com/Ki3FVgg4) with gdb, but it still gets killed. Before jumping to `e_entry`: `$rdi: 0x400a30` and `$rsp -> 1` (argc); jmp rdi goes to a `xor ebp, ebp`, then `push rsp` kills it. Is it missing something in the stack or registers? From the articles above, it looks fine

Comment: (I have also tried pushing 16 pairs of integer, integer pointers + the null one)

Comment: Still looking for help.

Comment: I just came across http://www.bitwagon.com/jumpstart/jumpstart.html which very likely contains the answer (at least for i386).