# Why does a standalone C hello program crash when used as a dynamic linker

Tags: gcc, glibc, elf, dynamic-linking

The following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (int j = 0; j < argc; j++)
    printf("%d: %s\n", j, argv[j]);
  return 0;
}
```

built into a statically linked PIE:

```
gcc -g -fpie main.c -static-pie -o ld.so
```

works fine:

```
$ ./ld.so foo bar
0: ./ld.so
1: foo
2: bar
```

But when I use that program as an ELF interpreter for *another* program:

```
$ gcc -g main.c -Wl,-I./ld.so -o a.out
```

it crashes like so:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7da84e2 in __ctype_init () at ctype-info.c:31
31    *bp = (const uint16_t *) _NL_CURRENT (LC_CTYPE, _NL_CTYPE_CLASS) + 128;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7da84e2 in __ctype_init () at ctype-info.c:31
#1  0x00007ffff7d9e3bf in __libc_init_first (argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffd728, envp=0x7fffffffd738) at ../csu/init-first.c:84
#2  0x00007ffff7d575cd in __libc_start_main (main=0x7ffff7d56e29 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd728, init=0x7ffff7d57ce0 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=0x7ffff7d57d70 <__libc_csu_fini>, rtld_fini=0x0, 
    stack_end=0x7fffffffd718) at ../csu/libc-start.c:244
#3  0x00007ffff7d56d6a in _start () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:120
```

Why is that?

All the addresses above are within `./ld.so` itself, so it crashes during its own initialization. Indeed the control would never reach `a.out` since `ld.so` exits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This took a bit longer to debug than I expected.

The crash is in:

```
Dump of assembler code for function __ctype_init:
   0x00007ffff7da84d0 <+0>:     mov    $0xffffffffffffffa0,%rax
   0x00007ffff7da84d7 <+7>:     mov    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rcx
   0x00007ffff7da84de <+14>:    mov    %fs:(%rax),%rax
=> 0x00007ffff7da84e2 <+18>:    mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x00007ffff7da84e5 <+21>:    mov    0x40(%rax),%rsi
```

with `$rax == 0`. When `ld.so` itself goes through this code, `$rax` is distinctly non-NULL. Obviously something went wrong during `TLS` setup, but what?

It turns out that GLIBC initializes its `_dl_phdr` from the `AT_PHDR` in the auxiliary vector, then iterates over all `Phdr`s to look for one with `PT_TLS` type.

If there isn't one, then GLIBC assumes that no `TLS` set up is necessary.

When `ld.so` runs directly, the kernel-supplied aux vector points to `Phdr`s for `ld.so`, `PT_TLS` is present, and everything works.

But when `ld.so` runs *indirectly* as the interpreter for `a.out`, the aux vector points to `Phdr`s for `a.out` (and not for `ld.so` -- this is as designed). Since `a.out` doesn't have any thread-local variables, it doesn't have `PT_TLS` segment either.

Conclusion: it is currently not possible to build an `ELF` interpreter with `-static-pie` and GLIBC, unless one is very careful to avoid thread-local storage. And avoiding thread-local storage currently appears to not be an option either: a trivial `int main() { return 0; }` still has a `TLS` segment despite not using *anything* at all from GLIBC.

Comment: The name `ld.so` looks suspect. Why do you use that name?

Comment: @wildplasser http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html may help you understand why I chose that name.